# linux python application pid exisisting check

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have strange problem with auto run my python application. As everybody know to run this kind of app I need run command:

```
python app_script.py
```

Now I try to run this app by cronetab using one simple script to ensure that this app isn't running. If answer is no, script run application.

```
#!/bin/bash

pidof  appstart.py >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
      python /path_to_my_app/appstart.py &
   fi
```

Bad side of this approach is that script during checking pid, checks only first word from command of ps aux table and in this example it always will be python and skip script name (appstart). So when i run another app based on python language the script will failed... Maybe somebody know how to check this out in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a question better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

However, it's common to use `pgrep` instead of `pidof` for applications like yours:

```
$ pidof appstart.py # nope
$ pidof python # works, but it can be different python
16795
$ pgrep appstart.py # nope, it would match just 'python', too
$ pgrep -f appstart.py # -f is for 'full', it searches the whole commandline (so it finds appstart.py)
16795
```

From `man pgrep`: *The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command  line is used.*

Comment: of course it solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Another way would be to run the script as `./appstart.py` (with something like `#!/usr/bin/python` in the file, and `chmod +x appstart.py` to make it executable). Pidof should find it then. But it seemed to be quite inconsistent on my systems when i tried it, so i use pgrep instead…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should better check for pid-file created in your application?
This will help you track even different instances of same script if needed. Something just like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import atexit

PID_file = "/tmp/app_script.pid"
PID = str(os.getpid())

if os.path.isfile(PID_file):
    sys.exit('{} already exists!'.format(PID_file))

open(PID_file, 'w').write(PID)


def cleanup():
    os.remove(PID_file)


atexit.register(cleanup)

# DO YOUR STUFF HERE
```

After that you'll be able to check if file exists, and if it exists you'll be able to retrieve PID of your script.

```
[ -f /tmp/app_script.pid ] && ps up $(cat /tmp/app_script.pid) >/dev/null && echo "Started" || echo "Not Started"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do the whole thing in python without the bash-script around it by creating a pidfile somewhere writeable.

```
import os
import sys

pidpath = os.path.abspath('/tmp/myapp.pid')

def myfunc():
    """
    Your logic goes here
    """
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # check for existing pidfile and fail if true
    if os.path.exists(pidpath):
        print('Script already running.')
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        # otherwise write current pid to file
        with open(pidpath,'w') as _f:
            _f.write(str(os.getpid()))
    try:
        # call your function
        myfunc()
    except Exception, e:
        # clean up after yourself in case something breaks
        os.remove(pidpath)
        print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        # also clean up after yourself in case everything's fine...
        os.remove(pidpath)
```